# Python: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python

I am writing a program to find adapters, and have made a class called 'Adapter'. When I pass in two arguments IDLE gives me an error saying I passed in three! Here is the code and stack trace:

```
#This is the adapter class for the adapter finder script

class Adapter:
    side1 = (None,None)
    side2 = (None,None)
    '''The class that holds both sides of the adapter'''
    def __init__((pType1,pMF1),(pType2,pMF2)):
        '''Initiate the adapter.

        Keyword Arguments:
        pType1 -- The passed type of one side of the adapter. ex: BNC, RCA
        pMF1 -- The passed gender of pType1. ex: m, f

        pType2 -- The passed type of one side of the adapter. ex: BNC, RCA
        pMF2 -- The passed gender of pType2. ex: m, f

        '''

        print 'assigining now'
        side1 = (pType1,pMF1)
        print side1
        side2 = (pType2,pMF2)
        print side2

sideX = ('rca','m')
sideY = ('bnc','f')

x = Adapter(sideX,sideY)
print x.side1
print x.side2
```

Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cody\Documents\Code\Python\Adapter Finder\adapter.py", line 28, in <module>
    x = Adapter(sideX,sideY)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

I don't understand what the problem is because I've only entered two args!

Edit: I'm new to the python language, though I know Java.
I'm using this page as a tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Your definition of `__init__` is way, way wrong.  What tutorial are you using?  Why did you write that? Why did you omit the `self` variable?  Please include the name or link to the tutorial you're using.

Comment: Your use of tuple expressions in your argument list is very non-idiomatic Python and would confuse many people.  I suggest that you not do that, especially since you just assign them as a tuple to something else anyway.  Please do not use very weird but strangely working Python constructs unless you have a really outrageously fantastic reason to.

Comment: different people learn in different ways, you may find diveintopython.org more suitable than docs.python.org

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the OP missed the `self`, but I don't even know what those tuples-as-arguments mean and I'm intentionally not bothering to figure it out, it's just a bad construction.

Codysehi, please contrast your code with:

```
class Adapter:
    def __init__(self, side1, side2):
        self.side1 = side1
        self.side2 = side2

sideX = ('rca', 'm')
sideY = ('bnc', 'f')
x = Adapter(sideX, sideY)
```

and see that it is both more readable, and does what I think you intend.

Comment: Thanks! My introduction to python has not gone as smoothly as hoped :P
It makes more sense to me now to just pass in two variables as lists.

Comment: I found Python a touch bewildering at first, and this was with dozens of languages under my belt. Useful nitpick: `sideX` is bound to a tuple `()` which is immutable as opposed to a list `[]` which is mutable.

Answer (score 13):

Method calls automatically get a 'self' parameter as the first argument, so make `__init__`() look like:

```
def __init__(self, (pType1,pMF1),(pType2,pMF2)):
```

This is usually implicit in other languages, in Python it must be explicit. Also note that it's really just a way of informing the method of the instance it belongs to, you don't have to call it 'self'.

Comment: Explained further in the Python doc on [Classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: to have `__init__` display correctly in the first line, you need to place backticks around it. Otherwise the double underscore makes it bold

Answer (score 5):

Your `__init__` should look like this:

```
def __init__(self,(pType1,pMF1),(pType2,pMF2)):
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is the way  Python says hello to everyone learning the language. Kind of Python's first bite.

You have to specify **self** in instance methods as first argument. So it should be.

```
  def __init__( self, (pType1,pMF1),(pType2,pMF2)):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Adapter:
side1 = (None,None)
side2 = (None,None)
'''The class that holds both sides of the adapter'''
def __init__(self,(pType1,pMF1),(pType2,pMF2)):
    '''Initiate the adapter.

Keyword Arguments:
    pType1 -- The passed type of one side of the adapter. ex: BNC, RCA
    pMF1 -- The passed gender of pType1. ex: m, f

    pType2 -- The passed type of one side of the adapter. ex: BNC, RCA
    pMF2 -- The passed gender of pType2. ex: m, f

    '''
    print 'assigining now'
    self.side1 = (pType1,pMF1)#i have changed from side1 to self.side1
    print self.side1#i have changed from side1 to self.side1
    self.side2 = (pType2,pMF2)#i have changed from side1 to self.side2
    print self.side2#i have changed from side1 to self.side2
sideX = ('rca','m')
sideY = ('bnc','f')

x = Adapter(sideX,sideY)
print x.side1
print x.side2
```

see the output below.

[image: program output]